# db migrations to insert a row in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am having a text file that contains users name.I want to extract users name from the text file and insert it into the table via db migrations.Here the extraction part works fine.There are no errors displayed with rake db:migrate.
But the data is not seen in the database.

```
class AddUsers< ActiveRecord::Migration
   def self.up
     i=0
     File.open("users").each do |line|
     if i>=4 && line=~/^(\s)+[a-z]+/
         word=line.split("|")
         word[0]=word[0].strip
         email=word[0]+"\@sandvine.com"
         puts "word=#{word[0]},email=#{email}"
         User.create :name =>#{word[0]}, :email => #{email}
         puts "created"
     end
     i=i+1
   end
end

 u=User.create(:name => "ramyameena", :email  => "ramyameena@sandvine.com",:password=>"sandvine",:roles=>{:id=>2,:name=>"Tester"})
=> #<**User id: nil**, name: "ramyameena", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, email: "ramyameena@sandvine.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$qIfRLKZlxviag9E0Gzvp8e3VKkOCaXraP7PnJC6vGMN....", reset_password_token: nil, remember_token: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil>

irb(main):012:0> u.errors.inspect
=> "#<OrderedHash **{:roles=>[\"can't be blank\"]**}>"
```

My users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
validates :roles, :presence => true
has_many :user_role_assignments
has_many :roles, :through => :user_role_assignments
has_many :tester_release_assignments
has_many :releases, :through => :tester_release_assignments
has_many :releases
has_many :ic_runs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_role_assignments
attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_ids
```

thanks,
Ramya.

Comment: `User.create` returns false if the insert isn't successful. `User.create!` raises an exception if it fails. Note this is different from the ruby convention, where the bang methods are usually the dangerous ones.

Comment: I am not getting any error or exception .But atill its not reflected in the table.

Comment: May be you are validating presence of some other field in your model thats why it is not creating that record.

Comment: I would recommend doing this in the db/seeds.rb file instead of a migration. Then just run `rake db:seed`

Comment: Hi Ramya, probably a bit late but as other users have pointed out, this will work in migration file, however it isn't the best way to handle this. Migrations are best left to the job they’re designed for: creating the structure of your database. Creating seed data in them can also lead to your seed data being scattered across several migration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#{...}` syntax is used to interpolate ruby in a string. You're using it correctly here:

```
puts "word=#{word[0]},email=#{email}"
```

but then incorrectly here:

```
User.create :name =>#{word[0]}, :email => #{email}
```

Here the `#` is actually commenting out the rest of the line (as you can even tell by the syntax highlighting here). It's curious that you don't get any syntax errors when running this code, but at best the result is undefined. What you want is this:

```
User.create(:name => word[0], :email => email)
```

as @dexter alread noted.

BTW, this is one reason to use braces even if you don't have to, because this:

```
User.create(:name =>#{word[0]}, :email => #{email})
```

would definitely throw a syntax error since the closing brace is commented out.

Comment: Hi Thilo, Thanks a ton for answering  me. The problem is I am not able to add it even via console irb(main):013:0> User.create(:name => "ramya", :email => "ramya@sandvine.com")
=> #<User id: nil, name: "ramya", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, email: "ramya@sandvine.com", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, remember_token: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil>
irb(main):014:0>
Here the id generated is null

Comment: In the console, try `u = User.create(...)` and then `u.errors.inspect` to check for errors that prevent saving the record.

Comment: Hi Thilo,Dexter, I have updated my code with the users model.The error I am seeing after u.errors.inspect is "roles can't be blank." I am not knowing how to give the roles in the user.create command. Please help me out here.

Comment: Well, `validates :roles, :presence => true` is the cause of that. You could assign a default role in a `before_create` callback if you don't want to pass one as a parameter to `User.create`. Read up on validations and callbacks at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thilo. Thaat worked out. I tried  before_create do |user|
   if !(roles)
   role=Role.find(1)
   user.roles(role)
   end
and it worked. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the create method you are calling. Everything after => would be a comment.
Should have been

```
User.create :name => word[0], :email => email
```

Also, instead of a migration, it's better to add this code to `db/seeds.rb` as this is seed data.

You can load the table data using `rake db:seed`